# can we club 2 virtual environments and use it as one for a python project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, virtual-environment

I have *dlib* package in a virtual environment. and *cv* in other virtual environment. What to do when I want to use both of them in a single python project?

Answer (score 0):

Update your requirements.txt file to include both packages and then rerun pip to install the required items.

https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/better-python-dependency-and-package-management-b5d8ea29dff1